# Installing GDAL in an R Kernel on Google Colab

Tags: r, google-colaboratory, gdal, rgdal

I'm trying to install the R package rgdal in my colab session. I know it needs the dependency GDAL to run, and normally this isn't a problem. I can find lots of help installing it using normal linux commands, but can't find anything on how I can install it from an R session.

This is my code if it helps:

```
install.packages("rgdal", dependencies=TRUE,repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')
Warning message in install.packages("rgdal", dependencies = TRUE, repos = "http://cran.rstudio.com/"):
“installation of package ‘rgdal’ had non-zero exit status”
```

Does anyone know if there's a way to install GDAL using R commands? Or a way to use magic commands like %%Shell in collab with an R Kernel? I'm fairly new to colab, but want my students to be able to run a script using rasters in colab using R.

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

After lots and lots of painful searching I found the answer:

`system("sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev libproj-dev")`

So R tells colab to install dependencies like normal linux.

Answer (score 1):

I think that now the installation of `rgdal` package is straightforward in a Colab R Kernel notebook:

```
install.packages("rgdal")
library(rgdal)
```

However, you may consider using pckage `sf` instead of `rgdal`, as `rgdal` will stop working on December 2023. To install `sf` in Colab R Kernel you should use the following code:

```
system("apt-get -y update")
system("apt-get install -y libudunits2-dev libgdal-dev libgeos-dev libproj-dev")
install.packages("sf")
library(sf)
```